# scrapy gettin coincident data

Tags: scrapy, web-crawler, repeat

```
import scrapy


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g298006-d740275-Reviews-Deniz_Restaurant-Izmir_Izmir_Province_Turkish_Aegean_Coast.html',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.css('div.quote'):
            yield {
                'author': response.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'member_info')]//div/text()").extract(), 
                'rating': response.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'ui_bubble_rating')]/@alt").extract() ,
                'comment_tag': response.xpath("//span[contains(@class, 'noQuotes')]/text()").extract(),
                'comment': response.xpath('//div[@class="entry"]/p/text()').extract()
            }

        next_page = response.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'unified')]/a[contains(@class, 'next')]/@href").extract_first()
        if next_page is not None:
            yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

This is my spider code. My problem is when i used crawl with json. there are so many repeated data from website

Comment: Your crawler seems to be fine. Could you elabore more on what do you mean by "repeated data"? As in duplicate review data?

Comment: Are you scraping book quotes from TripAdvisor? oO